# Install vCard using android app?

Tags: android, installation, vcf-vcard

Is there any way to install a ***vCard*** using ***android app***, as soon as it starts for the first time.
Although for running any block of ***code*** for the first time, I can use these lines ...

```
if (isFirstTime()) {
        //First time code
}
```

and

```
private boolean isFirstTime()
{
    SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean ranBefore = preferences.getBoolean("RanBefore", false);
    if (!ranBefore) {

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("RanBefore", true);
        editor.commit();
    }
    return ranBefore;
}
```

but how will I be able to install a vCard from app.

**Note:** Although I have the vCard already made, and can be put in the raw directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);  

 intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(storage_path+vfile)),"text/x-vcard"); 

  startActivity(intent);
```

**Edit**

Copy vcard to sdcard

```
private void copyAssets() { AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();

    String[] files = null; 

try { files = assetManager.list(""); } catch (IOException e) 

 { Log.e("tag", "Failed to get asset file list.", e); 

  } for(String filename : files) 
    { 

InputStream in = null; OutputStream out = null;

  try { in = assetManager.open(filename); 

 File outFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), filename);

  out = new FileOutputStream(outFile); copyFile(in, out); } catch(IOException e) { 

 Log.e("tag", "Failed to copy asset file: " + filename, e); } 

finally {

   if (in != null) { try { in.close(); 

   } catch (IOException e) { // NOOP }

    } if (out != null) { 

   try { out.close(); } catch (IOException e) { // NOOP } 
    } 
     }
       } 
     } private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException { 

   byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; int read; while((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1){ out.write(buffer, 0, read);

  } }
```

Then type the location where I have written `storage_path`

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(String.valueOf(R.raw.contacts))), "text/x-vcard");
        startActivity(intent);

Comment: the above comment highlights it up

Comment: I am doing this:
In **onCreate**
`Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File("raw/contacts.vcf")), "text/x-vcard");
startActivity(intent);
view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.view);
if (isFirstTime()){
view.setText("Contact has been installed.");}
}`
In isFirstTime():
`SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean ranBefore = preferences.getBoolean("RanBefore", false);
if (!ranBefore){
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putBoolean("RanBefore", true);
editor.commit();
}return ranBefore;}`